# The command "dotnet..." error while integrating OpenAPI / Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, nswag

I use Swagger Open API and while integrating I encountered the following error after building project:

*The command "dotnet "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.3.0\build../tools/NetCore31/dotnet-nswag.dll" run /variables:Configuration=Debug" exited with code -1. DemoProject with .NET DemoProject\src\WebUI.csproj*

I tried to change .NET Core version from 3.1  to 3 in *.csproj file, etc. but none of them solved the problem. I also have a look at many pages expaciallh GitHub and workarounds have not fixed the problem as well. Any idea?

***Update:*** Here is the details of the error (I have not find a proper fix on the web):

*"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection FluentValidation.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Reflection.Assembly, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLifetime)'.
at Demo.Application.DependencyInjection.AddApplication(IServiceCollection services)
at Demo.WebUI.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Code with .NET Demo\src\WebUI\Startup.cs:line 34
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.GetServiceProvider(String applicationName) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\AspNetCore\AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.cs:line 80"*

Comment: You're mixing your path separator characters in your path....and also appear to have a folder with two dots at the end of it that looks weird, or perhaps there was supposed to be a space before them and the last half of that is a separate relative path? Probably not, but the path looks very weird. Is there no other error output? Are you running that command yourself, or is some other tool running it for you? What happens if you run the command yourself?

Comment: Hi Mason, many thanks for your help. In this scene you men that that is due to paty error e.g. space or long path of project folder. SO, I move the root folder to C drive and retry again (now I am copying). I will inform you asap.

Comment: No...I meant that you have strange folder names if you have a folder called `build..` and that mixing path separator characters back and forward slashes in the same path is weird. And that you should look for other error output, and clarify for us whether you're running that command yourself or whether some tool is running it for you. And if you've been letting another tool run it for you, then you should try to run the command yourself to see if you get additional output.

Comment: SOrry, but although I typed it correctly, SO editor changes the message: "**The command "dotnet "C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.3.0\build\../tools/NetCore31/dotnet-nswag.dll" run /variables:Configuration=Debug" exited with code -1. DemoProject with .NET DemoProject\src\WebUI.csproj*"

Comment: In CMD cd to your project folder, copy and paste the failed command and run it in the command line. You will get more info than "exited with code -1".

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forget to build it via command and now I get the detailed error (I fixed the first time but now there is another error that causing still the pronlem. I added Update.

Comment: By using cmd, I get detailed error message and fixed the problem. Many thanks for your helps **mason** and **Remigijus Pankevičius** :)

Comment: @ClintEastwood Thanks for sharing your solution with the rest of us..